# How can I group device on discovery in Google smart home action?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a smart home skill already working fine with google home but when google home discovers devices for first time I want to group appliances into different rooms and relay this info back to google home. I know user can make rooms and assign appliances to them after sync event but I want to group them at the sync event so users wont need to do that from their end. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SYNC response you can return the [`roomHint` property](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync#response) for each device which will provide a signal to the Assistant after discovering it.